# wpquery properties last_query and last_result : should these be public or private?

Tags: wpdb

I've come across the following lines of code in `wp-includes/wp-db.php`:

```
/**
 * Last query made
 *
 * @since 0.71
 * @access private
 * @var array
 */
var $last_query;

/**
 * Results of the last query made
 *
 * @since 0.71
 * @access private
 * @var array|null
 */
var $last_result;
```

I wonder whether, since variables declared with var are public by default,
as can be seen [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php), whether there is an error in the documentation,
and whether var in this code snipped should be changed to private or public.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can guess from version number this code is *ancient*. So ancient in fact that `var` keyword is from **PHP 4** and is deprecated in PHP 5 (considered synonym of `public` for backwards compatibility).

So inline doc hints it is private because back then there was no actual property visibility in PHP language.

So *conceptually* it probably would have been protected in modern code (then it would probably need getters, because these two properties are highly useful for debug).

*Practically* however these will *eternally* be de–facto public, because changing them to private/protected would mean breaking backwards compatibility, which WordPress is dead set against.

Comment: Thanks. So I guess they should be public for backwards compatibility.